# Uniqueness of finite measures that agree on $\mathcal{H} \subset \mathbb{N}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, natural-numbers

Defining

$$A_k = \{k, 2k, 3k, ...\}$$

for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and

$$\mathcal{H} = \emptyset \text{ } \cup \{A_k : k \in \mathbb{N} \}$$

I have been able to show that

- $\mathcal{H}$ is closed under finite intersections
- $\sigma(\mathcal{H}) = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$

Finally, I need to show that two finite measures on $(\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$ that agree on $\mathcal{H}$ are the same.

I tried to use the Uniqueness of Measures Theorem but I got stuck when trying to find an exhausting sequence $(H_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{H}$ with $H_j \uparrow \mathbb{N}$ .

I wanted to take $H_j = \{1, 2, ..., j\}$ but I haven't been able to construct this sequence by taking only subsets of $\text{ } \mathcal{H}$.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Let $\nu, \mu$ be finite measures on $\mathbb{N}$ that agree on $H$. Since you have $\sigma(H) = P(\mathbb{N})$, it suffices to show that $F = \{E \subset \mathbb{N} : \nu(E) = \mu(E)\}$ is a sigma-algebra.

Comment: Ok, I see why this works. But @Mason how can I show that $\mu(\cup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \text{ } E_j) = \nu(\cup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \text{ } E_j)$ when $E_1,E_2,...$ aren't necessarily pairwise disjoint?

Comment: Sorry, I realize my proof that it is a sigma-algebra has an error, so that way might not work, or at least requires use of some non-trivial property of $H$.

Comment: @Mason, I think you were on the right track, but instead of showing F is $\sigma$-algebra directly, it can be shown that it's a Dynkin system, and then use the fact that $\sigma (\mathcal{H}) =\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ to show that it's actually a $\sigma$-algebra

Comment: $F$ is a monotone class so you can apply the monotone class theorem.  (IMO it's easier to remember the monotone class theorem than $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem, but it's all related.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $\mathcal H$ is closed under intersection, it forms a $\pi$-system, so this follows from some general result such as https://planetmath.org/uniquenessofmeasuresextendedfromapisystem

But the above link is not well-written. To give a concrete proof, let $B_i\in \mathcal H$ be a countable family, we show that $\mu(\cup_i B_i)=\nu(\cup_i B_i)$ if $\mu$ and $\nu$ agree on $\mathcal H$. Indeed $(\cup_{i=1}^n B_i) \uparrow (\cup_i^\infty B_i)$, and it sufficies to show $\mu$ and $\nu$ agree on $(\cup_{i=1}^n B_i)$. This can be done by the inclusion-exclusion principle as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability

Now for any $k\in\mathbb N$, we know that $\mu(A_k)=\nu(A_k)$ and $\mu (\cup_{k|i, i>k} A_i)=\nu (\cup_{k|i, i>k} A_i)$ by the last paragraph. Note that $A_k$ is the disjoint union of $\{k\}$ and $\cup_{k|i, i>k} A_i$, therefore $\mu(\{k\}) + \mu(\cup_{k|i, i>k} A_i) = \mu(A_k)$ and the same equality holds for $\nu$ as well, hence $\mu(\{k\} = \nu(\{k\})$ by $\mu(A_k)=\nu(A_k)<\infty$.

Note that finiteness is used in the last step and is necessary. For example, the counting measure $\mu(A) = |A|$ and the measure $\nu(A)=0$ if $|A|<\infty$ and $\nu(A)=\infty$ if $|A|=\infty$ agree with each other on all $A_k$, but they are different.